# whats preventing my server to respond

Tags: port-forwarding, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 8 server running on Windows 10.

I would like to make access to my server public, I have added a port forwarding in my router to port 5555 (the same port as the servers).

Using both the `localhost:5555` and my internal IP (ex: `192.168.1.2:5555`) I can access the server, but when using my public IP address (ex `x.x.x.x:5555`) it fails.

I have used port checking sites and 5555 is open, I even checked with Wireshark, and found out that there are some packets using the 5555 port are coming in, but for some reason they are blocked.

Below is a screenshot of the Wireshark capture and here is the [pcap file](https://mega.nz/#!UU8FjKRQ!0B__I7rg7kNPD6PVYIn4ooFm8vPHCWtKs688tab0S0k).

[image]

I even disabled the firewall, added exceptions for 5555 port and added exception for the tomcat executable, but nothing.

Whats happening here?

Comment: You haven't masked your IP in the images and linked file, however http://yourip:5555/ loads OK for me. I would guess that this is a routing issue explicitly within your LAN.

Comment: @adampski yea thank, its not static anyways, already changed, and yep it works outside my network.

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that this is the client-side trace, not the server-side?

It also appears that you are trying to access your external IP from inside your network. Do you have any evidence to suggest that this is an allowed configuration, it appears that your router is rejecting the connection attampt. The only way this could work is that the router would NAT the source and the destination IP addresses and I doubt that a home router would do that. Port forwarding is included in a router to allow access from the outside. You need to test from your friend's house or by using your mobile as a hotspot or by using a VPN proxy service.